# Describe an O(log n) divide-and-conquer algorithm to solve monotonously decreasing function problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

In this problem we consider a monotonously decreasing function f: N → Z (that is, a function defined on the natural numbers returning integer values, such that f(i) > f(i + 1)). Assuming we can evaluate f at any i in constant time O(1), we want to find n = min{i ∈ N | f(i) ≤ 0} (that is, we want to find the minimum value where f becomes negative).

[image: graph of monotonously decreasing function]

We can obviously solve the problem in O(n) time by evaluating f(1), f(2), f(3), . . . f(n). However I have to describe an O(log n) divide-and-conquer algorithm to solve the problem. (Hint: Evaluate f on O(log n) carefully chosen values ≤ n and possibly at a couple of values between n and 2n).

Can anyone help? I don't even know where to begin with this problem?

Comment: Let's say you've evaluated f(i) and the result was negative. Which section of the range of `i`s to choose from could you rule out for sure as being unhelpful to try next?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search

Answer (score 1):

First, find a range containing the target, of size O(n) in O(log n) time.

```
int mini = 1;
int maxi = 2;
while(f(maxi)>0) {
    mini = maxi+1;
    maxi *= 2;
}
```

The, just do a binary search in [min,maxi]

```
while(mini < maxi) {
    int testi = mini+(maxi-mini)/2;
    if (f(testi)<=0) {
        maxi = testi;
    } else {
        mini = testi+1;
    }
}
return mini;
```